# How to test if flag BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = TRUE works

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I got a complaint from a client that library i made was throwing an error when they try to import it. Error is saying: *"Module compiled with Swift 5.3 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.4 compiler"*. After some research i found out about ABI, and I understand the cause of this error.

Now I want to test if this solution works before shipping the fix. I downloaded a few older toolchain versions hoping that by switching them I could simulate this kind of situation. Setting the distribution flag for the library, building it with older toolchain and then importing it to a project with newest version of toolchain. However I still get the same error. Im I doing this right? What I am missing?